# How to print emissions from Observable<Observable<List<ResponseAllPhotos.Response>>>?

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java2

In the below code, i make http request via retrofit. as shown below the method getAllPhotos() returns `Observable<List<ResponseAllPhotos.Response>>`
what i want to achieve is, have a subscriber that emits in log statements, the url,title,thumbnailUrl and all the values in the data class shown below.

in the code section posted below, i attempt to display the above mentioned values which exist in the data class but the logs in the subscribe method never displays.

**code**:

```
//first attempt
/*var e = setupCommRequestService()?.
    flatMap {
        it.map {
            Observable.fromIterable(it)
                /*.map {
                    it
                }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe {
                    r->Log.i(LOG_TAG, "" + r.title)
                }*/
        }
    }*/

    //second attempt
    var e = setupCommRequestService()?.
        flatMap {
            it
        }

    var r = e?.map { 
        it
    }

    var t = r?.map { 
        Observable.fromIterable(it)
            .map { 
                it
            }
    }

    var z = t?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        ?.subscribe {
                r->Log.i(LOG_TAG, "" + r.url)//never works
        }
```

**interface**

interface CommunicationRequestService {

```
@GET("/photos")
fun getAllPhotos(): Observable<List<ResponseAllPhotos.Response>>

companion object {
    fun initRetrofit(ctx : Context) : Single<CommunicationRequestService>? {
        return Single.just(
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(
                    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
                )
                .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create()
                )
                .baseUrl(ctx.getString(R.string.BASE_URL))
                .build())
            .flatMap { retrofit -> Maybe.just(retrofit)
                .map { it-> it.create(CommunicationRequestService::class.java) }
                .toSingle()
            }
    }
}
}
```

**model**:

```
public object ResponseAllPhotos {
data class Response(val albumId : Int,val id : Int,val title : String,val url : String,val thumbnailUrl : String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done simply like this:

```
var disposable = setupCommRequestService()?.
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe {
                    r.forEach {Log.i(LOG_TAG, "" + it.title + "...") }
                }*/
        }
    }
```

You will get the list in subscribe in this example, so you can just tread it like a normal kotlin std list.